# Why does this solution tend to infinity as $t$ grows?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

Consider the ODE system
$$
\dot{x}=y,\qquad \dot{y}=x-x^2.
$$
Its Hamiltonian is given by
$$
H(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}.
$$
The solution that corresponds to $H=0$ and $x<0,y<0$ satisfies the equation
$$
\dot{x}=y=x\sqrt{1+\frac{2\lvert x\rvert}{3}}.
$$

It is said that this solution tends to infinity as $t$ grows.

How can I see that?

Comment: sorry, now I realise that its a bit harder that I thought. Anyway, $x(t)=\exp\left[\int_0^t \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}|x(\tau)|}\mathrm d\tau\right]$, and $\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}|x(\tau)|}\ge 1$, so that $\int_0^t \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}|x(\tau)|}\mathrm d\tau\ge t$.

Comment: Now, when seeing your answer, I think one might use the comparison principle. We have $\dot{x}\geq x$, so when setting $\dot{v}=v$ this has the solution $v(t)=c\cdot\exp(t)$ and we have $x(t)\geq c\exp(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$. The right hand side tends to infinity as t grows.

Comment: By the way... is $v(t)=c\exp(t)$ defined for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$? If yes then $x(t)\geq v(t)$ holds for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also level set $H(x, y) = 0$ minus equilibrium point has one non-compact connected component. Knowing vector field along this curve also tells you how $x(t)$ behaves.